# How to read .xls file with multiple header in R / Python for data processing?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, file-read, data-processing

I have this file which is specified below,

[image: .Xls file with multiple header]

As you can see it consists of many header layers, how can i read this file in R / Python so that i could get it in proper format for processing it?

Comment: What do you consider to be "proper?"

Comment: There are more than 2 headers for each column, how to manage that so i will end up having proper 1 header dataset!

Answer (score 0):

You can manually specify column names when reading with Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = r"/foo/bar/data.xlsx"
columns = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]

df = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=None, skiprows=7, names=columns)
```

To set mutli-level columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Foo':[1,2,3],'Bar':[2,4,6], "Baz": [3, 6, 9]})
columns = [("Cereals", "Rice", "Autumn"), ("Cereals", "Rice", "Summer"), ("Cereals", "Wheat", "Winter")]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
```

Comment: Okay, but each column in dataset comes under different category based upon multiple headers, so how can i be able to retain the hierarchy? for example  "Autumn" column is under "Rice" header and which is again under "Cereals and Millets".

Comment: Which is why I asked what you considered to be proper. See the edited answer.

Comment: Okay! i am handling this type of file for first time so bit confused, even i don't know what would be the proper format for this. Thanks for your suggestion i will try with this one.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas you could look at the Hierarchical indexing (MultiIndex) http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

But as your after Proper heading then do as "Batman" said above by reading in and applying your own column headings

Comment: Any solution using R?